# How to upload a file in a vb6 to a webservice

Tags: web-services, vb6

How to upload a file from vb6  to webservice

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you trying to access a service method that accepts a file as a parameter, and automate that from a VB6 application? If so, its going to be difficult, because you're probably going to have to write the proxy access later by hand. Not impossible, but tedious and likely time consuming...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to call a web service from VB6 you cannot do it directly. However, you can use Microsoft's SOAP toolkit and it will handle web service calls and file attachments.